# How to ensure that Everything can search within "comments" field in mp4 video files on a given PC?

Tags: everything

I am using the search tool [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com) on two PC's, a Windows 8 PC on which I am able to search within "comments" property of MP4 video files (e.g. if I set it myself manually), and another machine, a Windows 7 PC, on one which the same process (setting comments property, search with Everything fails).

Here are some experiments I've done:

- On Windows 7 PC - Searching within MP3 files with Everything, using "comment:<search_term>" - works (Everything uses singular "comment" function/term for this as per [these instructions](http://www.voidtools.com/support/everything/searching/).)
- Searching within the same MP4 files with Windows Explorer `comments:<search_term>` - works.
- Searching MP4 files with `content:<search_term>` - works in Everything, but is too slow for my purpose.

I am using the same major version of Everything (1.4). My understanding is that this somehow relies on a specific IFilter (?) being installed, but I can't quite tell how to troubleshoot it from here and what to try install (especially given that Windows Explorer is able to search within files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a user Error, it's not working on either of the PC's actually, so most likely Everything does not support it. The file I was experimenting and with which searching appeared working - was not a proper mp4 file.